# Why i not get the uploaded file in my php with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this file input field:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

and my ajax code is:

```
$(function () {
$('#pageContentForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = $(this);
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        $form = $(this);
        var actionURL = $form.attr('action');       
        var currentUrl = location.href;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionURL,
            data: form_data.serialize(),
...
```

and my php file:

```
if(!is_dir($img_target_dir)){
    mkdir($img_target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_file = $img_target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
if (!file_exists($target_file)) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
```

but not create the file just the directory...why can be happen this? Thanks for the helps!

Comment: add this in ajax `processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
                contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: processdata not working yet...user what can i see there? :D

Comment: You can't send a file in a form-urlencoded request. You need to send binary data using a `FormData` object. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: o, but i will see the other inputs also?